# Tirar redirecionamento de site no linode

Tags: wordpress, linux, redirecionamento-de-url, webserver

Eu tenho um site no linode e criei um subdominio, porém ele está sendo redirecionado para o domínio principal. Eu não tenho conhecimento em linux, alguém pode me ajudar?

Todos os links que não são: meusite.com.br são redirecionados para ele.

Comment: Tente ser mais específico [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/323052/edit) a pergunta e exemplifique melhor como explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente criar um arquivo *.htaccess* dentro do seu subdominio
(Deve haver uma pasta dentro da sua `/var/www/html/subdominio`)
Crie um *.htaccess* tanto no seu dominio principal `/var/www/html` quanto no `/var/www/html/subdominio`, espere uns 15 minutos ou teste em outro computador se ainda há o redirecionamento, caso persista, entre em contato com a linode e pergunte como solucionar,

***sua pergunta está fora do Escopo.***